# Change my function async: false to async: true with JQuery and Ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asynchronous

I have made a fonction in a javascript class which goes to a php file and return an information from the database.

This function works really well but I try to have the propriety **async: true,** but my function don't work with this propriety. (*I have this warning msg : L’utilisation d’XMLHttpRequest de façon synchrone sur le fil d’exécution principal est obsolète à cause de son impact négatif sur la navigation de l’utilisateur final.*)

Do you have any idea, how can I make it work ? A friend told me to try with "Callback" but I don't know how it works.

```
    getInfoFromDB: function() {
        var info;
        $.ajax({
            url: "./fonctions/ajax/members.php",
            type: "POST",
            dataType: 'html',
            success: function(data) {
                info = data;
            },
            async: false,

        });
        return info;
    }
```

Comment: success already contains a callback function... and could you find out *who* throws this error?

Comment: I'm assuming he's wanting to change it to async true and for it to still work like it is, procedurally.  There's most likely a disconnect here between sync and async work flows.

Answer (score 2):

You have to change your `getInfoFromDB()` to return something other than `info`. For example, you might [return a `Promise`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Using_promises) instead. If you just return the return value of [`$.ajax()`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/), you will get a `Promise`-like thing resolving to `data`.

```
getInfoFromDB: function() {
    return $.ajax({
        url: "./fonctions/ajax/members.php",
        type: "POST",
        dataType: 'html',
    });
}
```

But then you have to update everywhere that calls `getInfoFromDB()` to support async behavior. For example:

```
myObject.getInfoFromDB().then(function (info) {
    doSomethingWith(info);
});
```

From the documentation for [`jQuery.ajax()`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/):

> The jqXHR objects returned by `$.ajax()` as of jQuery 1.5 implement the Promise interface, giving them all the properties, methods, and behavior of a Promise (see [Deferred object](http://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object/) for more information).